# Prolog tries to find multiple solutions when only one exists

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I've made a basic predicate `ascending/1` to check if a list is in ascending order, on https://swish.swi-prolog.org.

```
ascending([]).
ascending([_]).
ascending([X, Y| T]) :-
    X =< Y,
    ascending([Y|T]).
```

It shows the following if I query `?- ascending([1, 2, 4, 6]).`:

[image: 1]

As in, it tries to find more solutions. Pressing `Next`, `10`, `100` or `1,000` just returns `false`, which is a mystery in and of itself - true and false at the same time? Maybe that's because of the anonymous `_`? Have I not defined completely enough? Why is it not just returning true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most Prolog systems implement *first-argument indexing*, which allows avoid creating spurious choice-points. Assuming that and a call with the first argument bound, in the case of your code, the Prolog runtime is able to able to distinguish between the first clause, whose first argument is an atom, and the two other clauses, whose first argument are lists. But not able (in general) to distinguish between the second and third clauses and avoid trying both for a goal where the first argument is a list. This results in the creation of a choice-point. Hence the results your get:

```
?- ascending([1, 2, 4, 6]).
true ;
false.
```

But we can improve on your solution. For example:

```
ascending([]).
ascending([Head| Tail]) :-
    ascending(Tail, Head).

ascending([], _).
ascending([Head| Tail], Previous) :-
    Previous =< Head,
    ascending(Tail, Head).
```

We will now get:

```
?- ascending([1, 2, 4, 6]).
true.

?- ascending([1, 2, 4, 6, 1]).
false.
```

Comment: You have ```ascending/1``` and ```ascending/2``` at the same time. Is that allowed?

Comment: Yes. Predicates are distinguished by name **and** arity (i.e. number of arguments).

Comment: So two predicates with the same name and types of arguments in the same order creates a choice-point?

Comment: I assume that by "two predicates" you mean two **clauses** of the same predicate? It depends. Consult the documentation of the Prolog system that you're using on its implementation of indexing, particularly *first-argument indexing*.